# How to efficiently add a column in a multidimensional numpy array with different dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have these two arrays.

```
a = np.ones((2, 3, 4))
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]]

[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]]]

b = np.ones(6) * 9
[9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9.]
```

Question. How do I efficiently get c such that it appears like this.

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]]

[[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 9.]]]
```

I've tried using np.c_, np.column_stack and np.insert but I'm struggling trying to figure out how to get the dimensions right. I can do it easily in the 1D and 2D case but anything more than that. :/

Comment: not the quickest, but it works for your small example …. np.c_[(a.reshape(6,4),b)].reshape(2,3,-1)

Comment: `np.concatenate([a, b.reshape(*a.shape[:-1], -1)], -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is (2,3,4).  To concatenate on the last axis, `b` has to be (2,3,1) (or more generally (2,3,n)).  `b.reshape(2,3)` gets you part way there, add a `np.newaxis` to get the rest of the way.  Or include the 3rd axis in the reshape: `b.reshape(2,3,1)`.

```
In [21]: np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(2,3)[:,:,None]),-1)
Out[21]: 
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.]]])
```

`np.c_` works with the same reshaping, `np.c_[a, b.reshape(2,3,1)]`.

`np.c_` (or `np.r_`) takes a string parameter that tells it how to expand dimensions if needed.  `np.c_` is the equivalent of `np.r_['-1,2,0',a, b.reshape(2,3)[:,:,None]]`.  That string parameter is a bit hard to follow, but playing around I found this works:

```
In [27]: np.c_['-1,3,0',a, b.reshape(2,3)]
Out[27]: 
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 9.]]])
```

Keep in mind that `np.c_` uses `np.concatenate` (as do all the 'stack' functions), so `In [21]` is the most direct version.  Still some people like the convenience of the `np.c_` format.

(`np.column_stack` joins on axis 1; the docs explicitly talk of returning a 2d array.  You have 3d case.)

`dstack` ('depth' stack) works: `np.dstack((a, b.reshape(2,3)))`.  It creates the 3d arrays with:

```
In [49]: np.atleast_3d(b.reshape(2,3)).shape
Out[49]: (2, 3, 1)
```

which in this case is the same as what the '-1,3,0' string does.